# Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, get, cross-domain

I am getting following error while i run my website:

> Failed to load
>   http://localhost:54721/api/Auth/GetMenuItemsByRoleId/null: The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values
>   'http://localhost:4200, *', but only one is allowed. Origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access

To solve this, I have added following code in every controller, which works fine.

```
  [EnableCors("http://localhost:54721/", "*", "*")]
```

So code will become like this:

[image]

But the fix is applied in every controller, this should be avoided.

Is there a better fix which i can do it one place ,say web.config?

My startup.cs as below:

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration httpconfig = new HttpConfiguration();


            WebApiConfig.Register(httpconfig);
            //enable cors origin requests
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            //app.
            ConfigureOAuth(app);

        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            double timeout = Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Timeout"].ToString());
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthserverOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
            };

            //Token generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthserverOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is and you should use it that way.

Create a config-class as seen in this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#scope-rules-for-enablecors).

Your cors configuration is incorrect anyway now. You have to allow `http://localhost:4200`, not the url of your api `http://localhost:54721`.

Comment: are you saying to change that?

Comment: Cant' be. CORS are for the browser. Your WebApi is not the browser-application that requests. Therefore the host http://localhost:4200 must be allowed and not the api-itself.

Comment: where to put localhost:4200

Comment: Just check the example I provided. [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

Comment: its looks like i need to put in all controller, my question is how i put it in one place instead of all controller

Comment: Yes, and that is explained in microsofts example. Just saying that your cors configuration is / was wrong.